# Adding a new column to a df each cycle of a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some modifications to a dataframe with a for loop. I am adding a new column every cycle of the for loop, however, I also drop this column at the end of the cycle. I would like to know if it is possible to store the values of this column per cycle, and create a new dataframe that is made of each of these columns that were generated per cycle. I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

newdf = np.zeros([1000,5])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0.0, 0.05], size=(1000,1000)))

for i in range(0, 10):
    df['sum']= df.iloc[:, -1000:].sum(axis=1)
    newdf[:,i] = df['sum']
    df = df.drop('sum', 1)
```

However, I get the following error:

> index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5

Thanks

Comment: What is `newdf`? What shape is it? What is the index on it vs on `df`?

Comment: Nathan, I modified the question to clarify it, I perform other operation to the df, however, for the purpose of the question I do not think it is necessary to provide those details. The main goal is explained above.

Comment: I get no errors with your code if you make the edits I just suggested (make `df` a `pd.DataFrame` and change `d.drop` to `df.drop`).

Comment: Do you still have an issue/question or does this work now?

Comment: @Nathan I have edited the question, the error rise because of the dimensions of the two dataframes. However, the dimension of the newdf on the question needs to be 1000 rows and 5 columns, that is the reason why I get that error, but I have not been able to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs not because of anything that has to do with `df`, but because when `i = 5`, `newdf[:, i]` refers to the sixth column of a NumPy array containing only five columns. If, instead, you initialize `newdf` through `newdf = np.zeros([1000, 10])`, or loop only over `range(5)`, then your code runs without errors.